# Translate JSON into Markdown list with jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I've got a JSON structure for projects and tasks:

```json
{
  "project1": [
    "task1a",
    "task1b"
  ],
  "project2": [
    "task2a",
    "task2b",
    "task2c"
  ]
}
```

which I'd like to convert to MD-like list:

```markdown
* project1
  * task1a
  * task1b
* project2
  * task2a
  * task2b
  * task2c
```

mainly using `jq` and `sh`/`bash`

the best I can do is:

```sh
jq '. | to_entries | .[] | .value |= "  * "+join("\n  * ")+"\n" | .key = "* "+.key'
```

but then I'm stuck trying to properly print `.value` string along with `.key`

Comment: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/json2md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another solution, without the update operator `|=`, without the `join()` builtin and without explicit newline characters `\n`:

```sh
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "* \(.key)", "  * \(.value[])"'
```

```
* project1
  * task1a
  * task1b
* project2
  * task2a
  * task2b
  * task2c
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uMN3jcUjPL)

Comment: The `*` all are on the same line. OP wan's the tasks to be indented.

Comment: @0stone0 Introduced the error in a re-edit. Reverted to working original. Thx for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `join()` and string interpolation:

```
to_entries[] | "* \(.key)\n  * \(.value | join("\n  * "))"
```

Will produce:

```json
* project1
  * task1a
  * task1b
* project2
  * task2a
  * task2b
  * task2c
```

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "* \(.key)\n  * \(.value | join("\n  * "))"' input
```

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IaZ1mIJwR-)

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Add `-r` to output raw strings instead of JSON, and use `| .key, .value` to output the key and value strings as separate items so they are shown on adjacent lines.

```
jq -r '. | to_entries | .[] | .value |= "  * "+join("\n  * ") | .key = "* "+.key | .key, .value'
```